# Does Apple reject application havin function setAllowsRubberBanding?

Tags: iphone

Will Apple reject my application which contains the function setAllowsRubberBanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly yes. I've heard of Apple rejecting apps using it because "non-public API functions are not allowed (cite: 3.3.1)".

Answer (score 2):

Using this method will get your application rejected. It is a private method and is not documented.